# how to insert data into table that has 2 columns in which col1 refers col2

Tags: javascript, next.js, supabase

I successfully inserted data by passing in hardcoded values (see 1st code snippet) to verify the relation between the 2 columns is valid.

I want to know if there is a way to reference `id`'s value in `reply_id`

This is how I did manually inserted data:

```
    const { data, error } = await supabaseServer.from('replies').insert({
        text: 'some text',
        id: 'e888f9c5-15b1-4e84-90bc-8bc2128a9338',
        reply_id: 'e888f9c5-15b1-4e84-90bc-8bc2128a9338'
    })
```

This is the Table schema in Supabase and a picture of the relation for readability:

```
  public.replies (
    id uuid not null,
    text text not null,
    reply_id uuid null,
    constraint replies_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint replies_reply_id_fkey foreign key (reply_id) references replies (id) on delete cascade,

  )
```

[image]

I miserably failed when trying the following as I simply referenced `id` in `reply_id`. What can i do differently?:

```
        text: replyText,
        id: randomUUID(),
        reply_id: id
    })
```

Comment: You can generate your id in separate statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
const id = randomUUID()
const { data, error } = await supabaseServer.from('replies').insert({
  text: 'some text',
  id: id,
  reply_id: id,
})
```

Comment: This worked! Is this considered hacky or a proper way to tackle the issue?

Comment: @Asad No worries. It's very straight forward standard javascript/ typescript!